# Select a position using draggable map and fixed marker in Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, maps

I'm newbie to iOS development and now trying to build a very simple navigation app using Google Maps SDK.
So I created a map and centered it to current position of user.

Now I need to implement the following functionality:

- make a fixed marker that always remains in the center in a screen;
- let the user move the map, so the fixed marker will be pointed to
  desired position.
- to write coordinates of this position in some
  variable when user taps on marker.

Can someone please advice with some ideas how to achieve this, or with some sample code?

Comment: hi sir how to make this type map in ios sdk please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the fixed marker, you can add a small UIButton on top of your map.
After the user pans the map and taps your button, you can get the location centered in map

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = mapView.camera.target;
```