# How to get location address using draggable map and fixed marker in Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

Currently i am developing an app like Uber, i am using Google Maps SDK.

My issue is: At present i am showing user current location in UITextField and at the same time i display GMSMarker on Google Map also.

Now the exact what i am looking is : if user should move map (with different locations). I need to get Address for that. i don't want GMSMarker dragging functionality

When ever user move google MAP camera position i need to get that location information like: Dolly app, Uber application, Ola cabs and etc..,

Can you please help me out how can i overcome this issue

I did some R & D for this . and i got some reference links also like: [Select a position using draggable map and fixed marker in Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987247/select-a-position-using-draggable-map-and-fixed-marker-in-google-maps-sdk-for-io)

Comment: This is not a platform for writing your algorithms. Please proceed with your task until you have specific technical questions.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: @Anil did you find any solution for this bevaiour

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you want to achieve but:

1. First, add a marker imageView in the center of the map view.
2. Get the coordinate of the center (position.target) of the map from the delegate `mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position`
3. Reverse geocode the coordinate by using

   [[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:coordinate
       completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {
           GMSAddress *address = [response.results firstObject];
   }];

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect answer for you. You see me answer...

Here you need to work on to get the current address.

Please open this link.

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position { }
```

In this function we can get latitude and longitude on centre of the map.

[How to move marker on the Google Map like Ola app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345449/how-to-move-marker-on-the-google-map-like-ola-app/51266064#51266064)

To get current location address

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!(error))
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
         NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Detected\n");
         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
         NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
         NSString *Address = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:locatedAt];
         NSString *Area = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.locality];
         NSString *Country = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.country];
         NSString *CountryArea = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", Area,Country];
         NSLog(@"%@",CountryArea);
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error %@", error);
         NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Not Detected\n");
         //return;
         CountryArea = NULL;
     }
     /*---- For more results 
     placemark.region);
     placemark.country);
     placemark.locality); 
     placemark.name);
     placemark.ocean);
     placemark.postalCode);
     placemark.subLocality);
     placemark.location);
      ------*/
 }];
 }
```